# Shared memory java in cluster configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere

My system is chatbot integrated with messenger, i will upgrade to cluster instead of one machine, so i will face a problem , when the user begin conversation , an record will be created in the machine memory, any further messages need to forward to the same machine because the memory is not shared between the machine s . I can create database to be shared between the machines but this solution is not acceptable because of the performance.
Any recommendations regards? I use ibm websphere server.
My question is , can i make shared memory between the machines?

Comment: Have you measured? You can't really share memory, but there are many distributed in-memory caches/databases/whatever that you could use. Redis is one popular option that might fit the bill. EDIT: and it can of course be used from Java.

Comment: Did you know dyncache in java with ibm websphere         https://github.com › cache › sample
dynacache/TestDistributedMap.java at master · kelapure/dynacache · GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a shared performant memory option you can use `Redis` / `Memcache`. There might be **network latency** a bit. However if your server's connection to `Redis` is **persistent** this network latency can be *negligible*.

If you want to anyway persist data in servers local memory along with the shared memory state, you can go for `Redis` with **Pub-Sub**, So in this setting every instance in the server will maintain data locally and will also **publish** it to the Shared `Redis` server, All server instance will also be **Subscribed** to required channels on the `Redis` so that they can sync data with other servers in real time. This way you wont have to *compromise* on the performance and will also make sure that every server instance has data upto date almost in **real time**.

Comment: Thank you but do you know  ibm webshpere distributed memory in java .